# How to setup babel-plugin-react-css-modules in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I really like the separation of className and styleName that babel-plugin-react-css-modules offers for global and local styles respectively, but have had some trouble getting the plugin to work with create-react-app.

I've tried installing the plugin by running

npm install babel-plugin-react-css-modules --save

... as it says to do in the project (github https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#css-modules) ...

... and have also used craco as suggested in a similar thread (#5113) to help overcome the limitations of create-react-app without the need to eject, but am still unable to import a scss file and reference to it using styleName.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something else here? Sorry if it's a noob question, I'm new to React and have been looking for a solution to this for a while now.

Comment: "still unable to import a scss file and reference to it using styleName"
babel-plugin-react-css-modules is for normal css modules (style.module.css) not for an scss file, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** add the plugin to **.babelrc** first.

```js
  "plugins": [
      ["babel-plugin-react-css-modules",
      {
        "webpackHotModuleReloading": true,
        "autoResolveMultipleImports": true
      }],.... 
  ]
```

**2.** add css rule in **webpack.config.js**.

below is my configuration that you can reference from.

make sure that

**2.1** option **modules** set to true.

**2.2** **localIdentName** follow this format. `localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"`

```js
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: { cacheDirectory: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: ExtractCssChunks.loader,
            options: { hot: true }
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader", //generating unique classname
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1, // if specifying more loaders
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: false,
              localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]" //babel-plugin-css-module format
              //localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]" //recommended settings by cssloader#local-scope , this option generate unique classname for compiled css
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: thanks @LancerAce, I've moved to using aphrodite now for css in js, but hopefully this will help anyone else who still wants to use babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Comment: "babel-plugin-react-css-modules" or "react-css-modules"? according to the README its the latest